# Сборка проекта из под Windows в Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

Очень нужно собрать проект (библиотеки и исполняемые файлы) на `Qt` в виндовсе на линукс. Нашел в интернете про сборку с линукса на виндовс, но ничего подробного без уже имеющегося приличного багажа знаний я не нашел. Подскажите где про это подробно расписано ,или может инструкцию может кто написать.
Спасибо.

Comment: https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/porting/qt/

Comment: Рекомендую другой подход. Устанавливаете виртуалку (например, VirtualBox), загоняете туда нужный дистрибутив линукса, ставите Qt и собираете ваш проект.

Comment: У меня имеется кроссплатформенный проект,библиотеки для win и Linux находятся в нем.Так же есть кроссплатформенный сборщик установочных файлов.В проекте есть одна библиотека,которая содержит уникальную информацию для конкретного пользователя.Необходимо реализовать весь процесс сборки проекта ( win и linux) непосредственно с одной ОС.Т.е что бы оптиимизировать сам процесс сборки дистрибьютива.

Comment: Всего лишь нужно воспользоваться mingw32 собрать этим компилятором, если библиотека не использует внутри операционные дырки то все будет ок что там что там.

Comment: mingw32 не хочет работать на Linux,Не получается настроить профиль